# Proofs using vectors

Tags: proof-writing, vectors

I am entirely new to proofs, never done them for year 12, so I'm wondering how to solve these questions? This isn't homework, im preparing for an undergrad math olympiad on my own, so if you could give solutions it would really help me learn how to show proofs.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For (a): consider the lower triangle. Then we have *a closed chain of vectors with $P$ as a vertex* starting in the lower left vertex to $P$ to the lower right vertex to the lower left vertex, namely $x(a+b)+ y(-b+a)-a=0$, collecting yields $a(x+y-1)+b(x-y)=0$.  Since $a$ and $b$ are linear independent, we achieve $x+y-1=0$ and $x-y=0$ from we happily derive $x=y=1/2$.

Comment: What is the significance of x in the equations? How is x and y related to the question? are they axes? Otherwise I get it. I think it just the proportion of the vectors in each vector? right? How do you achieve x + y -1 = 0? i dont get what is linear independent, although it seems obvious from wording

Comment: Call the down left vertex $O$. Clearly $OP$ is a part of $ a+b$, I've called it $x$.  Now $a$ and $b$ are linear independent, so $\lambda a+\mu b=0\implies \lambda=\mu=0$.